# Java Error handler

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, eclipse-plugin

I would like to be able to parse a .java file and get all the errors, fatal errors, and warnings. Is there a way to do that? I tried to extends DefaultHandler but it seems to encapsulate xml parser error and warning. 
Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Class `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` is for parsing XML files with a SAX parser; it does not have anything at all to do with parsing Java source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing an Eclipse plugin, then you will want to use `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser`.  See the documentation for how to use it.  You need to pass it some source, and then call the `getMessages` method on the resulting `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the package `javax.tools`. It contains an API to the Java compiler.

The API documentation of interface [`javax.tools.JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) has an example that seems to demonstrate what you want: list compilation diagnostics for a source file.